# Problem installing IIS on Windows XP

Tags: windows, iis, windows-xp

A bizarre problem occurred to me today. I tried to install IIS on a Windows XP computer, which is also part of a Windows domain. I followed the usual procedure:

- Go to "Add/Remove Programs"
- select "Add/Remove Windows components"
- Select IIS

Install procedes without a problem. However, when I go to http://localhost after install, I get the error: "You are not authorized to view this page". I expected the default IIS Welcome page here :(

Any idea what may cause this? I'm logged in as a domain user with local admin rights, can that have something to do with it?

ps: I'm a total noob to IIS. Just trying to install it on my pc to learn myself asp.net development.

pps: It's Win XP Pro SP3 to be exact

Answer (score 2):

Please Check for the default permissions of IIS and refer the below URLs to fix your issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271071